# Grav CMS: Reset data in form after submission

Tags: markdown, grav

I have a one page website based on Grav CMS with modular pages.
[image]

One of its pages contains a contact form.
It works fine, but the problem is that the `reset: true` option doesn’t work after submit. The sent data is left in the form and it could be sent once more.
I’ve tried leaving only minimum code parts with two fields, but this doesn’t make any sense.

Grav CMS 1.7.30

Form v5.1.6

`pages\01.home` contains `modular.lt.md` with:

```
content:
    items: '@self.modular'
```

The form is placed in the `contact.lt.md`:

```
---
title: 'Title'
menu: kontaktai
visible: true
cache_enable: false
form:
    name: kontaktu-forma
    template: form-messages
    fields:
        -
            name: email
            label: false
            placeholder: 'e.mail'
            type: email
            outerclasses: form-field
            classes: full-width
        -
            name: my-file
            label: 'Add files'
            type: file
            multiple: true
            limit: 5
            filesize: 6
            destination: user/data/files
            accept:
                - application/pdf
                - application/x-pdf
                - 'image/*'
        -
            name: telephone
            label: false
            placeholder: Telephone
            type: tel
            validate:
                required: true
        -
            name: message
            label: false
            placeholder: 'Info'
            type: textarea
            outerclasses: form-field
            classes: full-width
            rows: null
    buttons:
        -
            type: submit
            value: Submit
            outerclasses: form-field
            classes: 'full-width btn--primary'
    process:
        -
            email:
                from:
                    - '{{ form.value.email|e }}'
                to:
                    - '{{ config.plugins.email.to }}'
                subject: '[Message from] {{ form.value.name|e }}'
                body: '{% include ''forms/data.html.twig'' %}'
                attachments:
                    - my-file
        -
            reset: true                 
        -
            message: 'Thank you message'        
metadata:
    'og:url': 'url'
    'og:type': website
    'og:title': 'title'
    'og:author': author
addressTitle: 'Title'
published: true
aura:
    pagetype: website
media_order: '1.jpg,2.jpg'
---

Form text
```

Tried with `quark` theme but after submission the same code redirects to a blank page with "thank you" message

Comment: Try commenting out `template: form-messages`

Comment: Probably it relates to it... But once I remove `template: form-messages` after the data submission a whole page copy is loaded in the `message-success div`

Comment: Using a fresh Grav [One-Page Site](https://getgrav.org/download/skeletons/onepage-site/2.0.0) skeleton, I added page */user/pages/01.home/_contact/form.md* and added your code to the new contact module. Only commented out the template line. After submit, same page is rendered and shows correct "Thank you message" above emptied form. Note: 1) I named the module *form.md*, 2) the div's class is `toast toast-success`. Btw. `visible`, `cache_enabled` and `published` seem unnecessary.

Comment: Thank you, I will try to find out, what is causing the template issue and will report back. The `cache_enable: false` param is mandatory in such a way because a unique `ID` is generated every 24 or 12 hours (honestly I exactly don't remember)

Comment: Your answer is right. Please post it as an answer and I will accept it as a solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you comment out the line `template: form-messages`, the form should be correctly emptied/reset after a submit.

- Using a fresh Grav One-Page Site skeleton site ([download](https://getgrav.org/download/skeletons/onepage-site/2.0.0), [github](https://github.com/getgrav/grav-skeleton-onepage-site))
- I added page */user/pages/01.home/_contact/form.md*
- added your code to the new contact module.
- only commented out `template: form-messages`.

After submit, same page is rendered and shows correctly the "Thank you message" above
the form which is emptied/reset.

Note:

1. The name of the module should be `form.md` not `contact.md`, unless you are creating your own specific form template.
2. `visible` and `published` are `true` by default and don't need to be set.
3. `cache_enabled` should only be set to `false` if the page should not be cached because of some dynamic data being used.